# multiple joins in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I got some problem in querying. I got  2 tables:

```
declare @t1 table(pat_ref varchar(10),pas_id varchar(10), is_mnor char(1))
declare @t2 table (prev_pat_ref varchar(10),  pat_ref varchar(10))

insert into @t1 
values ('1','111','y')
      ,('5','115','y')
      ,('6','116','y')
      ,('2','112','n')
      ,('3','113','y')
      ,('4','114','n')

insert into @t2 
values ('1','2')
      ,('5','1')
      ,('6','5')
      ,('3','4')
```

Now I want:

```
pat_ref pas_id  is_mnor major_ref
1       111     y       112
5       115     y       112
2       112     n       NULL
3       113     y       114
4       114     n       NULL
```

But, with my query:

```
 select t1.* 
 , case when t1.is_mnor='y' then t3.pas_id else null  end as major_ref
 from @t1 t1
 left join @t2 t2 on t1.pat_ref=t2.prev_pat_ref
 left join @t1 t3 on t3.pat_ref=t2.pat_ref
```

I am getting:

```
pat_ref pas_id  is_mnor major_ref
1       111     y       112
5       115     y       111 ---this should be 112
2       112     n       NULL
3       113     y       114
4       114     n       NULL
```

Note: initial join columns  for @t1 and @t2 are `t1.pat_ref=t2.prev_pat_ref`

Comment: It looks like you actually have 3 tables.  What does t3 look like?

Comment: HI @kaz thanks for the reply, actually t3 is t1 as alias table to get pas_id from t1. Thanks

Comment: In your sample, you go two levels deep, with 5 connecting to 1 and 1 connecting to 2, where the chain terminates. If t2 had a row with (2, 4) would the expected result change to 114? In other words, are you looking to keep linking until the end or only up to a certain depth?

Comment: Pat reference 5 in t1, has a previous pat ref of 1 based on t2, and pat id 1 will have a pas_id of 111 based on t1. Your results are as expected. You need to explain your question better to get a helpful answer.

Comment: Change `('5','1')` to `('5','2')` in your `@t2` table ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to get bottom most relations from t2 and link those rows in t1. If this is true then you will need recursive cte to get bottom most rows and then 2 joins:

```
;with cte as(select *, prev_pat_ref as p, 1 as l from @t2
            union all
            select t.*, c.p, c.l + 1 
            from cte c join @t2 t on t.prev_pat_ref = c.pat_ref),
bot as(select *, row_number() over(partition by p order by l desc) rn from cte)

select t1.*, case when t1.is_mnor='y' then t2.pas_id else null end as major_ref 
from @t1 t1
left join bot b on t1.pat_ref = b.p and b.rn = 1
left join @t1 t2 on b.pat_ref = t2.pat_ref
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/530

Comment: You can probably simplify the query to have no joins in the external level.

Comment: @ypercube, I have to navigate to pass_id through bot and t2, how can I do this without join?

Comment: Hi @Giorgi Nakeuri, sorry for the late reply. It worked, this is what I want. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi @Giorgi Nakeuri, I think I am getting wrong data with this query, actually I included extra row in both tables I got wrong result. The query must return when t1.is_minor='Y' then it must return pas_id from t1 of is_minor='N'. I hope you got my point. Can you please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri , Thanks for the reply. I added ',('6','116','y')' on t1 and ',('6','5')' on t2 as 3rd rows and executed then I am getting wrong major_ref.

Comment: @user3583912, I have found the problem. Edited answer. The problem was `select t.*, c.prev_pat_ref, c.l + 1 `. Changed to `select t.*, c.p, c.l + 1 `

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri, I just changed as you suggested, It worked fine. Thanks again for your help and time.